# JQuery/Javascript/Ajax Passing Geolocation into URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code for the script is below, the map part works fine, and so does the connection to Weather Underground.  I can calculate what the URL should be based on geolocation, and I get the expected results when I go to that URL (ie JSON weather info for that location).  I can also return weather info for a set URL.  However, what doesn't work is:

```
url : url,
```

or

```
url : ""api.wunderground.com/api/MYAPIISHERE/conditions/q/" + position.coords.latitude
                + "," + position.coords.longitude + ".json",
```

Really at a loss with this one, guessing it's something to do with the Ajax not being able to access the co-ordinates?  I've removed my API key from the code/links, but it's correct in my version.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#locateme").click(function(){
    function locateme(position) {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude ),
          zoom: 16
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude ),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"You are here!"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
            function toggleBounce() {
              if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
              } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
              }
            }
            var url = "api.wunderground.com/api/MYAPIISHERE/conditions/q/" + position.coords.latitude
                + "," + position.coords.longitude + ".json";
            alert(url);
            $.ajax({ 
                url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/MYAPIISHERE/conditions/q/53.443647000000006,-1.20211.json", 
                dataType : "jsonp",
                success : function(parsed_json) { 
                var location = parsed_json['current_observation']['display_location']['city'];
                var temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_c'];
                alert("Provided by Weather Underground: Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_c); 
                }
            });
      }
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locateme);

    }       
    }); 
    });


</script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure from your problem description - when you call alert(url) does it display the expected result?

Comment: Alert(url) works as expected, and returns the info when input directly into the browser.

Comment: You should use your browser's dev tools to inspect the value of the response. Using alert is not very helpful. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging From my test with a couple assumptions, your code appears to work; the ajax request goes out and a response is returned. http://jsfiddle.net/lsubirana/np1q43f5/